# how to use encode and decode in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-3

In core php we use `url_encode()` and `url_decode()` so like this function we can use in laravel 4. If that's possible, please tell me how.

```
<p> <a href="userregistrations/{{ $users-> id }}">{{ $users-> username }}</a>
```

I want to encode `$users->id`. This id what is process or method to encode this id please help in decode as well.

Comment: I don't know about laravel , but the code there seems to be parsed by a template engine . Maybe you should encode before you pass it to the engine , but i think that the template engine takes care of encoding (at least it should, otherwise you should use php as a template engine).

Comment: Try `{{{ $users->id }}}`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provides a helper function called encrypt. All encrypted values are encrypted using OpenSSL and the AES-256-CBC cipher. Below is an example how to use this.

```
public function storeSecret(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->fill([
            'secret' => encrypt($request->secret)
        ])->save();
    }
```

Encrypted values are passed through serialize during encryption, which allows for encryption of objects and arrays. Thus, non-PHP clients receiving encrypted values will need to  unserialize the data. If you would like to encrypt and decrypt values without serialization, you may use the **encryptString** and **decryptString** methods of the **Crypt** facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('Hello world.');

$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

You may decrypt values using the decrypt helper. If the value can not be properly decrypted, such as when the MAC is invalid, an Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException will be thrown:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

try {
    $decrypted = decrypt($encryptedValue);
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    //
}
```

**Reference**: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/encryption

Comment: Encoding and encrypting are two different animals. I'm not sure if the thread owner meant that.